# What is a random piece of DNA called?

Tags: dna, terminology

If I picked up a DNA molecule and randomly snipped out a piece with scissors what is the scientific name for the resulting piece?

I'll confess right up front that I am not an academic or professional. I am retired and write science fiction for a hobby but I like everything in my stories that can be true and correct to be so.

In my current novella I have AI searching through the *entire* human DNA molecule (coding and non-coding) for a piece of DNA not related to grains but to a grain viroid. I am aware that viroids only infect plants but for my story I need a piece of this viroid to have spliced itself into the DNA of grains. That will then be found in the DNA we share with grains. Like the DNA we share with chickens, fruit flies, and bananas.

In my novella the reason for this is that it is a part of the trigger sequence for human metamorphosis which then takes place over ten thousand years. Just as things like body weight, food scarcity, etc. are triggers for metamorphosis in other animals, eating large amounts of grains is the trigger for human metamorphosis in my current story. Eating large amounts of grains means the development of agriculture and thus civilization. In my fictional universe where earth-like humans are not unique but common (due to convergent evolution) the birth of a new civilization means the beginning of their end unless they can escape the confines of their planet of origin before they destroy themselves via some version of the great filter.

Metamorphosis in other animals is an evolutionary strategy that is believed to have developed for similar reasons.

The metamorphosis that is triggered in humans leads to the development of AI and robotics and the next stage of life for the species. It enables them to spread to other worlds (which our organic bodies can't do in time) just like dragonflies leaving their pond.

"Why is humanity so compelled to create artificial life in its own image? Perhaps the caterpillar feels the same as it builds its chrysalis and for the same reasons." -- quote from my story, *Metamorphosis And The Messenger*.

So that's the big idea. As I was writing a paragraph about this search I wanted the correct word for a random piece of DNA. Google's AI only responded with names for specific pieces of DNA like genes, bases, exons etc. So since Google's AI is not smart enough to handle my question here I am. Maybe it's just called a "piece" but if there is a proper, scientific name I would prefer to use it.

Comment: Not in reference to this specific question necessarily, but it occurs to me you might like our [worldbuilding.se] stack. It exists for the express purpose of helping writers, artists, game-designers etc. design their fictional world. (Take their tour, read-up in their help centre before posting.)

Comment: Hi NetCentric, and thanks for posting your question. A few things: (1) you say "**the *entire* human DNA molecule**" -- the diploid human genome is comprised of 23 chromosome pairs, so 46 individual molecules (92 if you consider dsDNA to be composed of two interacting ssDNA strands). (2) I agree with Jiminy that your question is likely a better fit for the worldbuilding stack.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting the Worldbuilding stack. I was not aware of this resource but will check it out now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you were to literally chemically remove a piece, as with restriction enzymes or physical disruption, that would be a "[fragment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNA_fragmentation#:%7E:text=DNA%20fragmentation%20is%20the%20separation,gradually%20accumulates%20in%20a%20cell.)".

If you just mean a focal region of a genome, then "[locus](https://www.genome.gov/genetics-glossary/Locus)" or even just "region" would do.

I'm aware it's a SF premise and not meant to be super robust scientifically, but how do you see a pattern of descent in which a viroid that infected a grain (a plant) gets into a human (an animal that diverged 1 billion years ago, long before there was such a thing as multicellular plants)?

It's formally possible via [horizontal gene transfer](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4536854/) when people eat grasses I suppose, but then it's not part of the commonly inherited regions that we share with the other organisms you mention, as those branched off long before.

I suggest looking into work on [ultraconserved genomic elements](https://www.science.org/doi/abs/10.1126/science.1098119) as relevant to the mechanism by which the "AI" might work. These methods are relatively commonplace though, not sure that they merit the buzzword though.

Comment: Thank you for for answering my question. I really appreciate it. Also thanks for pointing out the pattern of descent and  horizontal gene transfer issues. As I pointed out I like things to be scientifically correct as far as possible so I will see if I can come up with another way to make the connection with agriculture. That part of the story is not yet written. If I can't find another mechanism well that's when the fiction part comes in. Thank you again.

Comment: To be clear, the "piece" OP is looking for should probably just be called a "gene". It would be reasonable to say that the AI is checking fragments of DNA for a gene introduced by a viroid, if taking all the premises as reasonable.

Comment: It's not clear to me why the AI would need fragments, though; given modernish technology they might as well operate on the whole genome. It seems they're looking for something suspiciously conserved from wheat to humans despite having no known function in either.

Comment: @BryanKrause I like "locus" in context as being a bit noncommittal about what exactly the piece of DNA is. If it's a viral genome/viroid relict, then "gene" isn't quite accurate. Yes, I agree that the work on ultraconserved elements could be relevant here; i will update to include.

Comment: @MaximilianPress I think of "locus" as a position in a genome rather than something functional. Even if the product is unknown (or if it's unknown that there's even a product vs a regulatory role) wouldn't gene be better?

Comment: @BryanKrause We commonly refer to "the YFG1 locus", where YFG1 is a gene. TAIR has genes under "locus" heading: https://www.arabidopsis.org/servlets/TairObject?accession=locus:2043520. I think of "gene" as meaning something rather specific as a defined transcriptional unit. I don't think this is what OP means, since "viroid" or "piece of viroid" is not necessarily transcriptional, and if it is, it is probably not a single unit. If we wanted to look for something in the archaic Johannsen sense of a generic, heritable-material-agnostic "unit of heredity", maybe then "gene" would be appropriate.

Comment: @MaximilianPress I think I'm leaning newer, rather than older, the definition that eg [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gene) captures as "a broad, modern working definition of a gene is any discrete locus of heritable, genomic sequence which affect an organism's traits by being expressed as a functional product or by regulation of gene expression"; specifically that final 'or'. But I suppose it's still unclear whether OP's chunk should be a single gene, or multiple, or what... I still think of "locus" as being a bit more like a street address with reference to a chromosome.

Comment: Of course there's a lot of overlap there, too, because if a building is on fire at 11 Wall St., whether you refer to the building or refer to it by address you still mean the same fire.

Comment: @BryanKrause Yes I think that we broadly agree, I find the wiki def'n to be a bit too vague but that's really a matter of taste. When we talk about the kind of algorithms that people use for this purpose I think that a "street address" is certainly appropriate, to follow your analogy.

Comment: @MaximilianPress Yes, I suppose as long as you phrase it as "you are looking for the place in the genome where this viroid-origin DNA exists" then a "locus" is fine; I still don't think that the *thing you find there* can be a "locus", but as you say, these can be somewhat interchangeable practically.

Comment: @MaximilianPress Thanks for the tip re: ultraconserved genomic elements. It looks like a promising alternative for the story given the pattern of descent issue you pointed out.